# how to know that RAID 1 is installed?

Tags: software-raid, sata, debian-lenny, raid1

recently we have a server crash, so we decided to mount a RAID 1 in our server. so we asked to the hosting, they told us that was needed to reinstall all the system again. so we make it, and now i have the doubt if the RAID is really working.

how can i know this? we are running debian lenny 64 bits and the raid is supposed to be running by software.

Regards,
Shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you run on bare metal or do you have a VM? If you run on a dedicated server, just run

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

and you will see if you have a raid.

Inside a VM I don't think it is possible (you just get a software block device from the host in all cases, unless they give you a block device per physical disk). You can try with a benchmark and compare the results with known single disk and RAID data.

To check for hardware raid, you can use `smartmontools`. If you do have a raid, you will not get SMART data running

```
sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda
```

Comment: say that the folder do not exist, and yes, is a dedicated server.

Comment: If you do not have /proc/mdstat, then you do not have software RAID.

Answer (score 4):

Pull the hard drive out. Is the server still running? Then you're using RAID.

Comment: This made me laugh :p

Answer (score 1):

In addition to md  there is the software RAID known as "fakeraid." Try running `dmraid -r` as root.

Answer (score 0):

`cat /proc/mdstat`